# Is it possible for the slope between two pivots to fall outside the range of -90 to +90?

Tags: python, charts, trading

I am attempting to display the slope between two pivots on the BTCUSD chart. Ideally, the slope should fall within the range of -90 to +90. However, I have noticed that in certain cases, the slope exceeds 200. How can I resolve this issue and ensure that the slope remains within the desired range?

```
if pivots:
    plt.plot(pivots, np.array(df["close"])[j], linestyle='-', marker='o', color='r')
    for i in range(len(pivots) - 1):
        indx1, close1 = pivots[i], np.array(dfpl["close"])[i]
        indx2, close2 = pivots[i+1], np.array(dfpl["close"])[i]
        slope = (close2 - close1) / (indx2 - indx1)
        plt.annotate(f"Slope: {slope:.2f}", (indx2, close2), xytext=(10, 10), textcoords='offset points', color='r')
```

Comment: What does "desired" range mean?  The slope is what it is.  It's not really up to you "approve" of it.

Comment: Let me explain it with an example. Suppose the BTC/USD price was 20,000 on January 1, 2023, and it increased to 21,000 on January 31, 2023. To calculate the slope between these two prices, you divide the price difference by the time difference. In this case, the slope would be (21,000 - 20,000) divided by the time span from January 1, 2023, to January 31, 2023. By performing the calculation, you can determine the slope accurately.  The expected slope for the price chart between these two points would naturally be around +89 and -89. Does it make sense?

Comment: Day 18th: Price 19541 $    |     Day 23rd: Price 23891 $    |    slope = (23891-19541) / (23-18) = 870 !!!

Comment: No, "desired" slope does NOT make sense in any way.  Bitcoin is extraordinarily volatile, and its graph looks like a roller coaster.  The slope between those 5 days IS +870.  The average change over 30 days has absolutely no impact on the average change over 5 days.  That's just calculus.

Comment: Yes, Tim, you're correct. There was a misunderstanding on my part regarding the difference between slope and angle. I managed to resolve the issue by using the following code: 
angle = math. Degrees ( math.atan ((close2 - close1) / (idx2 - idx1)))

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should use the absolute value in your equation:

```
slope = (close2 - close1) / abs(idx2 - idx1)
```

Comment: Due to the nature of dates, where idx2 and idx1 represent two different dates, the difference between them will always be positive.